# Transfer a table to Excel in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter

I tried the code from the link 
http://kahayan-faisal.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-export-data-to-excel-file-using.html
to transfer table into Excel but the code does not work.

> Type: ParseError Message: syntax error, unexpected '':C''
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' Filename:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Autopoint\application\controllers\Export.php Line
>   Number: 62

the line is

```
$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$rowexcel':C'.$rowexcel)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
```

I am using this feature for the first time so I do not have much idea on it. It would be great help if someone would view the code and help me or provide me another reference.

Comment: use query_to_csv for generating csv and rename file to xlsx if you dont require formatting or coloring.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax should be:

```
$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$rowexcel.':C'.$rowexcel)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
```